# Trouble converting multi-dimensional array to dropdown with optgroup using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wish to convert [this array](http://pastebin.com/B2bvFB8Z)to an optgroup inthe following way while using the Codeigniter form_dropdown function.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Thomas More Kempen">
    <option value="22">D001</option>
    <option value="23">D002</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Thomas More Geel">
    <option value="2">G001</option>
    <option value="8">A102</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
value is lokaalId
```

So far I could show the "Thomas More ..." in optgroup with objects ad chlildren, but so far no dice.

Solved:
I changed the way I get my Data from the DB:

```
function getAllMetCampus() {
        $this->load->model('campus_model');
        $alleCampussen = $this->campus_model->getAll();

        foreach ($alleCampussen as $campus) {
            $lokalen = $this->getAllOnCampusId($campus->id);
            foreach($lokalen as $key=>$value){
                unset($lokalen[$key]);
                $lokalen[$value->lokaalId] = $value->lokaalNr;
            }
            $result[$campus->naam] = $lokalen;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Then I just `echo form_dropdown($result);`

Comment: whats your code you are trying ... please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper function is looking for arrays inside the main array not `stdObjects` as your linked input shows, see the source: [form_helper:336](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L324)

You will have to convert your input, maybe something like this:

```
$options = array_map(function($item){
    return (array)$item;
}, $options);
```

Or since your input seem to be coming from a db query result, use the `result_array()` or `row_array()` methods instead of the `result()` or `row()` when you fetch them.

You should be getting an error like this, without converting:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 2):

Optgroups arent that hard in codeigniter:

if you want this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Thomas More Kempen">
    <option value="22">D001</option>
    <option value="23">D002</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Thomas More Geel">
    <option value="2">G001</option>
    <option value="8">A102</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can simply loop your array like this:

```
function getAllMetCampus() {
        $this->load->model('campus_model');
        $alleCampussen = $this->campus_model->getAll();
        $options = array();

        foreach ($alleCampussen as $campus) {
            $options[$campus->naam] = array();

            $lokalen = $this->getAllOnCampusId($campus->id);
            foreach($lokalen as $lokaal){
                $options[$campus->naam][$lokaal->lokaalId] = $lokaal->lokaalNr
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
```

Makes me wonder, why do you have an ID for campus and lokaal,
Are there more rows of campus with the same name, and lokalen with the same number in each campus? It looks like an bad pratice for primary keys to me, can you comment on this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the question is four years old already and in the meantime I've graduated.
The delivered data model was part of a class assignment.